# Regex to capture everything after the word vlan1 and before the line 100 vlan_mgmt

Tags: regex

My regex is `(?<=vlan1)(?s)(.*$)` and it captured everything after "vlan1". I just wanted to capture all the interfaces only. Can someone help me change the regex above to capture only interfaces after vlan1 and before 100 vlan mgmt line?

```
60 vlan1
fa0/1, fa0/2, fa0,3
fa0/4, fa05

100 vlan_mgmt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to capture the value you could omit the positive lookbehind `(?<=vlan1)` and match it instead, then use a capturing group for your values.
Inside that capturing group repeat matching all lines that are not followed by a newline, 1+ digits and the word `vlan`

You might use:

```
vlan1\n((?:(?!(?:\d+ vlan)).*(?:\n|$))+)
```

That will match

- `vlan1\n` Match vlan and newline
- `(` Capture group

  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `(?!(?:\d+ vlan))` Negative lookahead, assert not 1+ digits, space and vlan
    - `.*` Match any char except a newline 0+ times
    - `(?:\n|$)` Match newline or end of string
  - `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
- `)` Close capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9atgmQ/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `(?<=vlan1\n)(?s)(.*$)(?=\n100)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bawnmW/1)